# Joining (Ctrl + J) multiple paths bevelled by a shape ruins the whole shape

Tags: modeling, bevel

So I was trying to make hair for my character and watched a tutorial that explained how you could create simple hair by bevelling a curve path by a curve shape. So I had done this and placed it on my character's head while editing some of the hair by shrinking or fattening the path's vertices, but then when I want to finally join all the hair together, the hair then changes shape, how can I make sure this does not happen and the hair maintains shape? The pictures below are before and after I join all the hairs that are being bevelled by shape than being adjusted through shrinking and fattening.
[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Be aware of modifiers. The short answer is to apply them before "Joining".

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely caused by modifiers either having different settings or operating differently because of a sudden change in relativity to the origin point since upon joining the objects it uses the origin from the selected object, If this is the case I would suggest ensuring all the origins are in the same location before joining them. If not make sure there are no differences in modifier settings before merging them or simply apply the modifiers before merging the objects together as user DontWalk commented